# Perform a GROUP BY-like command in UNIX

Tags: grep, awk

I am having a text file like the following:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ... n    <-- column numbering
1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 ... 0
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ... 1
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 ... 0
0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 ... 0
0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 ... 1
```

Actually is a very sparse matrix, where binary values. In each row there should be more than one 1s and in each column at least one 1.

What I want to do is find out which columns have let's say less than 2 1s. For example in my matrix above I would like to get rid of columns 3, 5, 6 and 7 because they only have one 1.

Is there an UNIX command to do that? Probably I need a Group by-like (SQL) command and then keep track of which columns are less than a certain number, but I don't see how I could do it.

Comment: Nope. If you were zapping *rows* that had <2 1s, then it would be no problem.  The original question will require some programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `awk` to traverse the matrix and count the number of 1s and 0s using the following script:

**count.awk**:

```
NR != 1 {
  for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i)
    count[i] += $i;
}

END {
  ORS = ",";
  for (i=1; i<=length(count); ++i)
    if (count[i] >= min)
       print i
}
```

If you execute this script using

```
awk -v min=2 -f count.awk matrix.txt
```

you will get a line of columns that have two or more 1s, in this case "1,2,4,8,9," (note: you can change the `min=X` to any minimum threshold you want).

Now, use `cut` to print out only the columns that we want:

```
cols=$(awk -v min=2 -f count.awk matrix.txt); cut -d' ' -f${cols:0:-1} matrix.txt
```

This stores the `awk` output in a variable (the reason for this is that `awk` returns a list of columns with an extra `,` at the end. I "slice" the comma out when I pass the cols to `cut`).

Set the delimiter for `cut` to "space" (`-d' '`), and the output columns to the comma-separated list from `awk`, with the last comma sliced out (`-f${cols:0:-1}`).

Output:

```
1 2 4 8 9 n
1 0 1 1 0 0
0 1 0 0 0 1
1 0 0 1 1 0
0 1 1 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 1 1
```

If you want to output the columns with fewer than `min` 1s (ie. columns 3, 5, 6, 7), just reverse the condition of the `if` statement in the `awk` script above to read `if (count[i] < min)`.

Output:

```
3 5 6 7
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
1 0 1 0
0 1 0 1
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Actually the code is probably having some problems. What is the NR != 1 part for? EDIT: It works with NR>0.

Comment: @ddmichael `NR != 1` is used to skip the heading line with the column numbering. It says "if the record number (NR) is not 1, then do the following actions." On my system `NR > 1` also works, but **NOT** `NR > 0`. I'm surprised it works for you -- maybe your `awk` starts numbering from zero??

Comment: Ah, yes you're correct.